# Powerapps Search all even if filtered

Tags: html, search, filter, powerapps

I have my first app working off a Sharepoint list, I have two filters and a search box, the filters are working fine but the search is not working.
Basically what I am looking for is if they use the search function that it does not matter what filters is in place and it searches all the data.

below is the code I have but this just pulls the filtered data not the searched:

```
Search(Filter('KB Import',kb_category = 
Dropdown2.Selected.Result||Dropdown2.Selected.Result = "*All",workflow_state 
= Dropdown1.Selected.Result || Dropdown1.Selected.Result = 
"*All"),TextSearchBox1.Text,"short_description","text")
```

Comment: When you nest a Filter inside of a Search function, you'll get the items in the SPO list that match *both* the filter conditions and the search conditions. Is that what you are seeing? If not, can you given an example of an item that is returned that matches the search but not the filter?